# Breaking away a process started from C#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, process, redirectstandardoutput

I have some existing code making use of `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` to start a child process.  It also uses `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` to capture the output stream of that process.  This much is working fine.

I also need to attach it to a [job object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I have code which does this as well, and it works fine provided that the process is not already attached to a job.

Unfortunately, that isn't always the case, so I need to create the process with the `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` flag.  This is where I'm stuck.

As I see it, there are two possible ways forward from here:

1. Somehow convince `Process.Start` to pass that one extra little flag.
2. Abandon the `Process` class, fall back to raw `CreateProcess`, and (somehow) redo the output redirection.

I'm not really sure how to do either of these, or if there's some middle ground which might also work.  Has anyone else run into this before and have some ideas/code?

Comment: How are you attaching a process to a job? Is it possible to detach a process from a job in a similar manner?

Comment: I'm using `AssignProcessToJobObject`.  Sadly jobs are a one-way street -- once a process is assigned to a job it can't be unassigned, and unless you can pass that flag to `CreateProcess` then child processes will inherit the job of their parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, I've gone with option #2.  I think I've worked out how to do the output capturing, though I haven't tested it extensively yet.

Still interested in alternative ideas, though.